# Make JSF wait for database

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee

I have a JSF page to submit form values to a database. When clicking a button, values are submitted to my ManagedBeans and written to a database via JPA. Then the updated values from the database should be displayed in a dataTable at the same page.

The problem is: The database is too slow, so JSF seems to render the page before those are in the database (thus only rendering the older ones already there). How can I make JSF wait for the database to finish writing the values? I can figure out how to get the current phase of a lifecylce, but not how to stop it...

Answer (score 1):

> *The problem is: The database is too slow, so JSF seems to render the page before those are in the database (thus only rendering the older ones already there). How can I make JSF wait for the database to finish writing the values?*

This makes honestly no sense. JSF just does the job you told it to do in the bean's action method. Apparently you are not reloading the list from the DB after the persist. Perhaps you are referring to that the updated item is only visible when you refresh the page so that a new GET request is fired which reloads the data from the DB.

The canonical approach is to just reload the data from the DB immediately after the save.

```
public void save() {
    someService.save(some); // Save item in DB.
    list = someService.list(); // Reload list from DB.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Maybe it really does not make sense - but the strange thing is that the problem only arises if I am creating a whole new row in the database. Just updating a single value, changes are directly written into my table...